# Blazor Run Microtasks Taking 6-7 Seconds

Tags: performance, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to figure out why this modal is taking time to start up. The same modal code on other pages displays nearly instantly, so I doubt it is the actual modal component. I have expanded on the original/simple modal but it gets us what we want, and as I said, works fine on other pages.

**Modal.razor**

```
<div class="modal @modalClass @(IsNested ? "modal-nested" : "")" id="@Id" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: @modalDisplay">
  <div class="modal-dialog @Size modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    @if (isOpen)
    {
      <div class="modal-content">
        @if (NoHeader == false)
        {
          <div class="modal-header align-items-start @HeaderClass" style="@HeaderStyle">
            @if (Header != null)
            {
              @Header
            }
            else
            {
              <h2 class="modal-title">@Title</h2>
            }

            @if (AllowTitleClose)
            {
              <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" @onclick="() => Close()"></button>
              </div>
            }
          </div>
        }
        <div class="modal-body @BodyClass">
          @Body
        </div>
        @if (Footer != null)
        {
          <div class="modal-footer @FooterClass" style="@FooterStyle">
            @Footer
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>

@if (showBackdrop)
{
  <div class="modal-backdrop @(IsNested ? "modal-nested-backdrop" : "") fade show" @onclick="() => Close()"></div>
}
```

This may be more than we need for this article, but here is the code behind.

**Modal.razor.cs**

```
public partial class Modal
{

  [Parameter]
  public String Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

  [Parameter]
  public String Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;

  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment Header { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment Body { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment Footer { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public string Size { get; set; } = "modal-xl";

  [Parameter]
  public string FooterClass { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public string FooterStyle { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public string BodyClass { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public string HeaderClass { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public string HeaderStyle { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public bool IsNested { get; set; } // Use this when you have this modal on top of another modal

  [Parameter]
  public bool AllowTitleClose { get; set; } = true;

  [Parameter]
  public bool NoHeader { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback OnClose { get; set; }

  [Inject]
  private IJSRuntime jsRuntime { get; set; }

  public string modalDisplay = "hidden;";
  public string modalClass = "fade";
  public bool showBackdrop = false;

  public bool isOpen { get; set; } = false;

  public async Task Open()
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Modal's OPEN:                                        {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");
    modalDisplay = "block;";
    modalClass = "show";
    showBackdrop = true;

    System.Console.WriteLine($"  Modal's OPEN Pre  JS Invoke of hidePagesScrollbar: {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");
    await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("hidePagesScrollbar");
    System.Console.WriteLine($"  Modal's OPEN Post JS Invoke of hidePagesScrollbar: {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");

    isOpen = true;
    //////System.Console.WriteLine($"  Modal's OPEN Pre  StateHasChanged");
    //////StateHasChanged();
    //////System.Console.WriteLine($"  Modal's OPEN Post StateHasChanged");
    System.Console.WriteLine($"  Modal's OPEN Complete:                             {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");
  }

  public async Task Close()
  {
    modalDisplay = "none;";
    modalClass = "";
    showBackdrop = false;

    if (IsNested == false)
      await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showPagesScrollbar");

    isOpen = false;
    StateHasChanged();

    if (OnClose.HasDelegate)
      await OnClose.InvokeAsync();
  }
```

I have left my current comments in there and even commented out the `StateHasChanged` to see if that affected anything and it does not seem to.

Here is a super simple page where I am seeing the lag:

**TestPage.razor**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" @onclick="ShowApprovalsModal">
  Show Approvals
</button>

<Modal @ref="modal" Title="Approvals Modal" Size="modal-nearly-fullscreen">
  <Body>
    <Approvals />
  </Body>
</Modal>
```

**TestPage.razor.cs**

```
    public partial class TestPage
    {
        public Modal modal { get; set; }

        public async Task ShowApprovalsModal()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"ShowApprovalsModal CLICKED:                          {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");
            await modal.Open();
            System.Console.WriteLine($"  Back from ShowApprovalsModal click:                {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");
        }

        public async Task ShowProjectInfoModal()
        {
            await piModal.Open();
        }
    }
```

The following is just the `OnInitializedAsync` of the actual modal content I am displaying. Once this loads, everything works fine. Even when I close it

**Approvals.razor.cs**

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  System.Console.WriteLine($"Initing the Approvals UI:                            {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");
  await Utils.ShowSpinner();
  System.Console.WriteLine($"  Approvals, GatherUsersApprovals:                   {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");
  await GatherUsersApprovals();
  System.Console.WriteLine($"  Approvals, SearchUsersActive:                      {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");
  var users = await UsersService.SearchUsersAsync(new UserSearchModel { IsActive = true });
  Users = users.OrderBy(x => x.AccountLogin);
  Utils.HideSpinner();
  System.Console.WriteLine($"  Approvals Init completed:                          {System.DateTime.Now:ss.ffff}");
}
```

One thing to note, say I click on the button to show the modal, wait for the long microtasks to run, then close the modal and click the button to show it again. That time it is quite responsive and comes back in about a second.

So here are the times I have logged. I have ran this numerous times and are always quite consistent. So, on the page "ShowApprovalsModal" it even comes back all within about 1/100th of a second. Great! Then there is about a 6-7 second pause before the Approvals code's `OnInitializedAsync` even starts. The numbers below are actual `DateTime.Now` seconds and then fractions of that second.

```
ShowApprovalsModal CLICKED:                          28.1210
Modal's OPEN:                                        28.1290
  Modal's OPEN Pre  JS Invoke of hidePagesScrollbar: 28.1290
  Modal's OPEN Post JS Invoke of hidePagesScrollbar: 28.1340
  Modal's OPEN Complete:                             28.1340
  Back from ShowApprovalsModal click:                28.1340
Initing the Approvals UI:                            34.6830
  Approvals, GatherUsersApprovals:                   36.4080
  Approvals, SearchUsersActive:                      40.9460
  Approvals Init completed:                          41.1800
```

I ran the profiler just to see what might be going on and that is where I found the click events microtasks. I assume this is all Blazor and js interop stuff but have no real idea. I am not even sure how to use the Profiler (using Edge, but I know it is a Chromium browser.)

Here is an image of the overall profile.

[image]

Here is when I clicked on the large click event.

[image]

Lastly, here is a more detailed look at the event.

[image]

So what is actually happening within those microtasks. Can I disable them, make them faster or is something on my very simple page causing more microtasks to run that really should?

**UPDATE 1**

In response to @henk-holterman I have added the code requested below. However, please help me understand how `GatherUsersApprovals` is the issue when the following happens before it and is the entire reason for this post. **Why is there a 6.5 second gap?**

```
Back from ShowApprovalsModal click:                28.1340
Initing the Approvals UI:                          34.6830
```

I have no issue with the 2 seconds here:

```
Initing the Approvals UI:                          34.6830
Approvals, GatherUsersApprovals:                   36.4080
```

Or even the 4 seconds here, because there are actually things happening:

```
Approvals, GatherUsersApprovals:                   36.4080
Approvals, SearchUsersActive:                      40.9460
```

Code:

```
private async Task GatherUsersApprovals()
{
  Pending = await ApprovalsService.GetPendingApprovalsAsync();
  var myComplete = await ApprovalsService.GetCompleteApprovalsAsync();

  Completed = myComplete.Data;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<ApprovalViewModel>> GetPendingApprovalsAsync(int userId, bool isApprover)
{
  var predicate = CreateUserSelectionPredicate(userId, isApprover);

  return await repository.SelectManyAsync(query => query
    .Where(predicate)
    .Where(q => q.ApprovalStatusId == (int)ApprovalStatuses.WaitingForApproval)
    .ProjectTo<ApprovalViewModel>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider));
}

public async Task<Paged<ApprovalViewModel>> GetCompleteApprovalsAsync(int userId, bool isApprover, int currentPage = 1, int pageSize = 20)
{
  var predicate = CreateUserSelectionPredicate(userId, isApprover);

  return await repository.SelectPageAsync(
    query => query
      .Where(predicate)
      .Where(q => q.ApprovalStatusId != (int)ApprovalStatuses.WaitingForApproval)
      .OrderByDescending(q => q.ApprovalDate)
      .ProjectTo<ApprovalViewModel>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider),
    currentPage - 1,
    pageSize);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

@HenkHolterman Not sure exactly "which library" you are wanting me to show, so here is the full `.csproj` file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>SWIFT.Client</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>SWIFT.Client</AssemblyName>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.1</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.1</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.0.1-beta</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.GuardClauses" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="BlazorApplicationInsights" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Humanizer.Core" Version="2.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.5" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Mirality.Blazor.Routing" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Radzen.Blazor" Version="3.18.9" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\SWIFT.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\SWIFT.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Security\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)\sass\sass.bat $(ProjectDir)\Styles\app.scss $(ProjectDir)\wwwroot\css\app.css" />
  </Target>

  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <UserProperties pages_4test_1json__JsonSchema="json" />
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>

</Project>
```

I am not sure when I can take the time to get a minimal version. I have other pages and they are speedy when triggered.

```
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between">
    <h2 class="mb-0">My Work</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ShowProjectInfoModal">
      Add New Project
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<RadzenDataGrid AllowFiltering="true"
                AllowPaging="true"
                AllowSorting="true"
                Data="@data"
                EmptyText="@EmptyResultsText"
                FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple"
                IsLoading="IsLoading"
                LogicalFilterOperator="LogicalFilterOperator.And"
                PageSize="10"
                ShowPagingSummary="true"
                TItem="MyWorkViewModel"
                Style="max-height: 65vh">
  <Columns>
    ...
  </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

<ProjectInfoModal @ref="piModal" PAPDetails="papDetails" OnSave="@SaveProject" />
```

Code behind:

```
public ProjectInfoModal piModal;

public async Task ShowProjectInfoModal()
{
  await piModal.Open();
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you for your response, I have added an update.

Comment: You may want to add which library you use and what happens in that Form. You're right that GatherUsersApprovals() isn't the real bottleneck it's hard to see what is,  Best would be a [mre].

Comment: Hopefully this will will @HenkHolterman, thanks for your reply.